# ASCII chars to integer

Tags: c, hex

I have a char array with a hexadecimal number stored like this `'0' 'x' '3' '2'`.

Or in C:

```
char * hex = "0x32";
```

`0x32` is the ascii code for `2`. I don't want to use any functions, but how can I store the value `2` in an integer?

So in the end I would have:

```
int dec = 2;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. The easiest way to get from `'2'` to `2` is to subtract `'0'`.

Comment: When you say you don't want to use any functions, you mean you want to implement again each function like `atoi` ?

Comment: And if *you* want to implement it, then what are you asking us to do?

Comment: The '3' is in the sixteens place and the '2' is in the ones place. '3' is 3 steps from '0' on the character code number line. Does that help?

Comment: The fact that you have to do something so convoluted suggests there may be bigger issues with the way your application is designed. What is the reason you actually need to do such an operation?

Answer (score 1):

```
int dec = (int)strtol(hex, NULL, 16) - '0';
```

is one way, and is fully portable. You might want to think about not passing `NULL`, so you could validate the contents of `hex`.

If you don't want to use any functions (?!), then nick the source code from your C standard library's version of `strtol`.